# Start Activity from browser background mode

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am trying to start the Activity from browser's background mode by sending custom url from java script like this

```
  window.location = "ctl.notification://recive";
```

This url handles by the activity defined with intent-filter

```
 <activity
        android:name=".NotificationURIActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notification_uri" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="ctl.notification" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The problem is that I can easily start my activity when browser is in foreground, but I need to do it when browser is in background mode.

Any help is appreciated ...